# three.js: how to check if an object is added or removed dynamical from the scene?

Tags: object, runtime, three.js, addition

Say you have a light and at some point you removed it, then you want to add it again.

You do adding and removing in render function which keep getting called by animate function.

You check if a check box is checked, you add (scene.add(light), else remove (scene.remove(light).

So, in this case, are we adding a lot of objects (lights) when check box is checkedin render function, is there any performance impact? We could add a flag or counter to not keep adding, but is there something else we can do like check for isInstanceof?

Comment: You can do `if (light instanceof THREE.PointLight)` but how would this help you. Anyway, the performance impact should be minimal but does depend on the number of objects you are removing adding. If these are a lot, you could try using the `visible` attribute of the Object3D.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think, because we already defined and initiated the light, instanceof will always see the light as instance of some light even if we remove it from the scene. We could use change event to solve it, but when we use if($('#somelight').is(':checked')), checking happens for every render() call. I think also even we check and add for every call, only one light is added because we are not defining or adding a new light.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out for server sided controll of the canvas/threejs renderer you could just store these objects in an array, and if you use a loader or other meshes you can just add a name to it.

this will be easier(in my case) to check if an object is already in the scene.

example:

```
var AllObject = []; // <-- the array that holds all objects in the scene.

var scene = new THREE.Scene(), // <-- creates basic threejs scene
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();  //<-- creates WebGL renderer
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ); //<-- set the size of the canvas
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); //<-- add canvas to body

/* now the part that i use to check if an object is already in scene. */
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
AllObject[NAMEOFOBJECT] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); //<-- here comes the trick, insted of making a new var object just put it into an array with [] not {}!
scene.add( cube );
```

now if you use these if statement below you can find your object and the if statement will check the array for its `indexOf` position number.

```
if(~AllObjects.indexOf("NAMEOFOBJECT"){
 // you could remove the object by using scene.reomve(AllObjects.NAMEOFOBJECT);
// or just say for example console.log("Object already in the scene");
}else{
 // here you can make the object if it doesn't exists.
}
```

`NAMEOFOBJECT` can be anyname you want.